# Spotify API - Create temporary playlist

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, playlist

I'm trying to create a temporary playlist through Spotify API with this code:

```
var playlist = models.Playlist.createTemporary("My temporary playlist");
models.Playlist.createTemporary("My temporary playlist").load('tracks').done(function(playlist) {
    playlist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:4VqPOruhp5EdPBeR92t6lQ"));
    playlist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5HF5PRNJ8KGtbzNPPc93tG"));
});

var list = List.forPlaylist(playlist);
document.getElementById('playlistContainer').appendChild(list.node);
list.init();
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
core.js:4 - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'load'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, still not sure why this works and my previous code didn't, but there you go:

```
models.Playlist.createTemporary(playlist_name).done(function(playlist) {
  playlist.load('tracks').done(function(loadedPlaylist) {
    loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:4VqPOruhp5EdPBeR92t6lQ"));
    loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:5HF5PRNJ8KGtbzNPPc93tG"));
  });

  var list = List.forPlaylist(playlist);
  document.getElementById('playlistContainer').appendChild(list.node);
  list.init();
});
```